# what is the も in this phrase mean?

Tags: words

学校の先生もとても優しいです

What does the first "も" mean?

Comment: Do you know what も usually means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to be 100% sure without context, but this も is probably an inclusive も, as in "also".

So something like "The school teacher is also very kind".  But you need to be careful with this translation because the "also" applies to the teacher, not to kindness.

For example:
"Bob is kind.  Alice is also very kind."
ボブは優しいです。アリスもとても優しいです。

[Also note how the も "replaces" は (which itself "includes" が) so as a case marker it carries all three functions "additive", "subject", and "topic".]

Comment: Nice answer , up vote for you!　BTW use, ボブは優しいんです。アリスもとても優しいんです。if you really want to convey how nice Bob is.

Comment: That's a very good point, but might be too advanced for many people who would find this answer useful, so I'm torn on whether to edit it in.  For anyone who is curious, I recommend reading the "The 「の」 particle as explanation" section of this page of Tae Kim's excellent grammar guide: 
http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/nounparticles